# in Jquery codes using variables

Tags: jquery, html, contextmenu

How can i use EditPhoto variable in this codes??
i add my full codes here.
how can i use EditPhoto variable in here:
** EditPhoto :{name: "Edit This Photo", icon: "edit"} **

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#sortable li').click(function() {
            id = $(this).attr("id");
            id = id.replace("GaleriSirala_", "");
            alert(idBul);
            EditPhoto = ("edit-photo&EditNow=" + id);
        });
    });

    $(function() {
        $.contextMenu({
            selector: '.context-menu-one',
            callback: function(key, options) {
                var m = "index.php?sayfa=" + key;
                $(location).attr('href', m)
            },
            items: {
                EditPhoto :{name: "Edit This Photo", icon: "edit"},
            }
        });

        $('.context-menu-one').on('click', function(e){
            console.log('clicked', this);
        })
    });

    $j('.GaleriListele').click(function() {

        alert( $(this).childen('a').attr('id'));

    });
```

Comment: Where you want to use `EditPhoto`?

Comment: in here:   items: {
            EditPhoto :{name: "Edit This Photo", icon: "edit"},
        }

Comment: Are you really sure you want to use that as the property name? `edit-photo&EditNow=id` looks like a URL parameter string, why would that be a property name?

Comment: Because it is context-menu.Url look like this: index.php?sayfa=edit-photo&EditNow=6

why asked to me?.

Comment: Is [this](https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/docs/items.html) the documentation for `items` that you're using? I don't see anything like that there.

Comment: why not working like this?
var items = {
        items[GaleriDuzenleLinki] = {name: "Fotoğrafı Düzenle", icon: "edit"},
        "galeri-sil&galeriSil=<?php echo $listele['id'];?>": {name: "Fotoğrafı Sil", icon: "delete"}
    };

Comment: i try this. but not working:

 var items = {};
        GaleriDuzenleLinki = ("galeri-duzenle&galeriDuzenle=" + idBul);
        items[GaleriDuzenleLinki] = {name: "Fotoğrafı Düzenle", icon: "edit"}
        "galeri-sil&galeriSil=<?php echo $listele['id'];?>": {name: "Fotoğrafı Sil", icon: "delete"}

Answer (score 0):

use the [] notation:

try something like this

```
var items = {}

EditPhoto = ("EditPhoto&EditNow=" + id);

items[EditPhoto] = {name: "Edit This Photo", icon: "edit"}
$(function() {
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: '.context-menu-one',
        callback: function(key, options) {
            var m = "index.php?page=" + key;
            $(location).attr('href', m)
        },
        items: items
    });
```

Comment: hi, it is not worked, then i add my full codes on the top..How can i use EditPhoto variable in my codes??

Comment: what do you mean by not woked?

Comment: there isn't "i can't" i its "i won't do it", what do you mean by "i can't"?

Answer (score 0):

i try like this.
but right click context menu is to opening.

```
var items = {}
    EditPhoto = ("EditPhoto&EditNow=" + id);
    items[EditPhoto] = {name: "Edit This Photo", icon: "edit"}
    $(function() {
        $.contextMenu({
            selector: '.context-menu-one',
            callback: function(key, options) {
                var m = "index.php?sayfa=" + key;
                $(location).attr('href', m)
            },
            items: items
        });
    });
    $j('.GaleriListele').click(function() {
        alert( $(this).childen('a').attr('id'));
    });
```